# Mormons claim to be from the tribes of Israel (revealed via a "Patriarchal Blessing"), is this offensive to the Jewish community?

Tags: christianity, shevatim-12-tribes, genealogy, abraham, ephraim

It has come to my attention that members of the the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints (LDS), or more commonly known as Mormons, receive what is called a patriarchal blessing.

This "Patriarchal Blessing" is unique in that it is only given once in a person's lifetime and it divulges information about their pre-existing life, their strong talents, the challenges that they will face throughout their lifetime on Earth, what their individual purposes/roles in life are, stating which tribe of Israel they belong to by lineage, and special blessings that are to come, which are contingent on their obedience and living life in accordance to their commandments. You can read more about Patriarch Blessings from their own website here: https://www.lds.org/topics/patriarchal-blessings?lang=eng.

But I'll cite directly from the website concerning what the Patriarchal Blessings says in regards to the lineage aspect of the blessing. :

> Declaration of Lineage: A patriarchal blessing includes a declaration
>   of lineage, stating that the person is of the house of Israel—a
>   descendant of Abraham, belonging to a specific tribe of Jacob. Many
>   Latter-day Saints are of the tribe of Ephraim, the tribe given the
>   primary responsibility to lead the latter-day work of the Lord. 
>   Because each of us has many bloodlines running in us, two members of
>   the same family may be declared as being of different tribes in
>   Israel.It does not matter if a person's lineage in the house of Israel
>   is through bloodlines or by adoption. Church members are counted as a
>   descendant of Abraham and an heir to all the promises and blessings
>   contained in the Abrahamic covenant (see Abrahamic Covenant).

**Does it offend the Jewish community that Mormons claim that they are direct heirs of the House of Israel, and have full access to the Abrahamic covenant?** Or do we, for the most part, shrug it off and say "to each their own. They can believe what they wanna believe"?

*I'm not sure whether to feel like the are encroaching on my identity or to just smile and be flattered that they want to be from the House of Israel too?*

**Have any rabbis made any official statements regarding their reactions of the Mormon's claim to the House of Israel?**

Comment: I doubt any official statement has been made about this. Jews generally aren't in the habit of officially denouncing every incorrect claim ever.

Comment: While it might be offensive and insulting, it is not as bad as their pretending to "convert" deceased Jews. If they claim to be descended from Jews, then they are claiming to be mamzerim and subject to the death penalty as idol worshipers. Somehow, I do not think that this is what they have in mind when making this claim.

Comment: Why is this more offensive than any Christian or Muslim claiming that they are the real chosen nation and the Jews have been replaced?

Comment: @user6591, Oh, I didn't state in anyway say this is "more" offensive or compare it to supersesessionism. But, the difference here is, is it's not just a "theological replacement"; they actually believe they are direct descendants by blood and identify themselves as part of the House of Israel as well. I just didn't know how to respond when my Mormon friend told me. He was really excited to tell me about it -- like we had a shared heritage/family history.

Comment: Do they? If it all depends on a declaration and can be dependent on adoption, then it's not genetic is it?

Comment: As he explained it and as I read, they believe most of them are direct descendants by blood -- but a few are mentioned to be "adopted" into the tribes -- it all depends on what their "Patriarchal Blessing" specifies. Makes me wonder if they ever looked at their genetic makeup :)

Comment: @sabbahillel Even as non-Jews they are subject to the death penalty as idol worshipers. I don't know why people get worked up about this. They, like most people, do silly things. Moving on...

Comment: This question seems to be (about Jews but) not about Judaism. I don't see how it's on-topic on this site.

Comment: from an historic point of view, almost all nations, when christianized, made an effort to link itself to the biblical genealogy, in england, celts to Yitro, in Italy to Noach, this is not a mormonal invention.

Comment: @msh210 It's not that different from http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13266/759 or other similar 'etiquette' questions.

Comment: @DoubleAA that Q's about something that the asker, at least, seems to think is a Judaism thing. (*Maybe.*) This Q is only about a being-a-Jew thing.

Comment: @msh210 What about http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23462/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41028/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73806/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22506/759

Comment: @DoubleAA let's continue this in chat, rather than on this post. (And not now, sorry.)

Comment: ..just to keep things in perspective here, these are the folks whose founder dictated their main text while putting his face into a big hat with magic stones in it-while the "golden plates" were wrapped up across the room. Oh yeah, and what was he arrested and found guilty of a few years earlier? For fraudulently telling folks, at a good price, where buried treasure was allegedly to be found on their property.  How'd he do that?  By looking into a hat with magic stones in it....as Double AA wrote--moving on, all right...

Comment: I'm not offended as much as I am humored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their claim to be Jews is more flattering, I should think.

So long as they don't deny the claims of (actual) Jews, then it would be "each to his own."  The Catholic church and most normative Christians have a similar-enough claim (from a Jewish POV, they all claim to be the modern holders of the covenant), and no-one bothers to denounce their ideas these days.

On the other hand, I believe it's normative Mormon practice to refer to all non-Mormons, *including* Jews, as "Gentiles."

Note that while they say they descend from the "House of Israel" and Abraham, they don't specifically claim to be Jews themselves.

So, if their calling Jews "Gentiles" means they're claiming that only Mormons are the *real* Jews, it's offensive.

If, OTOH, "Gentile" is simply their nomenclature for "non-Mormon," then there's no more reason to be insulted by them than by most Christians.

Can someone get an authoritative Mormon source to clear this up?

P.S. *Everyone* I know finds their practice of post-mortem "conversion" offensive, but this Q isn't about that.

Comment: I don't find the conversion practice offensive

Comment: Really?  The only alternative I can think of is that it's too ridiculous to offend.  Is that your view, or do you have another way of looking at it?

Comment: long time reader, first time poster, so the site won't let me reply to the other answer. Short story, that vernacular faded away in the early 70s, and has never been used in our scriptures (which refer to the Jews as Jews, members of the Church as the Tribe of Ephraim by adoption and or birth, and sometimes referring to the prophesied Jewish kingdom as Judah and the Church as Israel) As someone who was once seriously pursuing a path to conversion and who absolutely loves the Jewish people, I can tell you that the Latter Day Saint view of Judaism and Jews in general is one of immense respect, g

Comment: I believe you, so far as you speak about your own feelings.  OTOH, in the late 80's, I attended corporate training and shared an apartment with a fellow from SLC in his 20's.  He was unfailingly polite, and it was clear from his tone and manner that he meant nothing negative by it, but it was the only time anyone ever called me a "gentile."